# Any advice/proper way to make an Android app who can execute task on Windows/Linux?

Tags: android, linux, windows

I want to make an app who can execute program on my computer or execute music to train myself.
Do you have any advice on how to connect them both ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This may seem obvious, but an Android application, by definition, runs on an Android device.

Given that it's not running on your Windows or Linux computer, it can't "execute a task" on one of those computers.

What it can do is communicate with an application running on the other computer.
The possibilities include IP network communication (TCP or UDP), and Bluetooth.

In either case (or if you pick some other communication protocol) you will likely need to write a custom application that runs on the Windows or Linux computer, so that your Android app has something to talk to. That custom application can then "execute tasks" on the Android application's behalf.

You could either write separate applications for Windows and Linux, or write a single, cross-platform application. There are many ways to write cross-platform applications, what you choose will largely be dictated by what exactly you need it to do, and what programming languages you know.

Comment: Thank you for you answer